# No 'iDisplayStart' key in GET request dictionary

Tags: jquery, python, datatables, pyramid

I'm using the [SqlAlchemy DataTable example](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlalchemy-datatables/0.1.6) as my foundation for trying to implement `DataTables`.
Everything was working, I did multiple screen refresh and everything worked perfectly. Now when I clicked on refresh, I suddenly get this error `KeyError: 'iDisplayStart'`. I haven't changed anything or at least I think so. Here is my python method

```
@view_config(route_name='simple_example', request_method='GET', renderer='json')
def simple_example(request):
    # defining columns
    columns = []
    columns.append(ColumnDT('ixTransformerTurnsRatio'))
    columns.append(ColumnDT('iPrimaryVoltage'))
    columns.append(ColumnDT('iSecondaryVoltage'))
    columns.append(ColumnDT('sTap'))
    columns.append(ColumnDT('decRatioA'))
    columns.append(ColumnDT('decExcitationA'))
    columns.append(ColumnDT('decDeviationA'))
    columns.append(ColumnDT('decRatioB'))
    columns.append(ColumnDT('decExcitationB'))
    columns.append(ColumnDT('decDeviationB'))
    columns.append(ColumnDT('decRatioC'))
    columns.append(ColumnDT('decExcitationC'))
    columns.append(ColumnDT('decDeviationC'))

    # defining the initial query depending on your purpose
    query = DBSession.query(TTransformerTurnsRatio)

    # instantiating a DataTable for the query and table needed
    rowTable = DataTables(request, TTransformerTurnsRatio, query, columns)

    # returns what is needed by DataTable
    return rowTable.output_result()
```

and here is my html for the table:

```
<table class="table" id="simple-example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>PV</th>
            <th>SV</th>
            <th>Tap</th>
            <th>Ratio A</th>
            <th>Excitation A</th>
            <th>Deviation A</th>
            <th>Ratio B</th>
            <th>Excitation B</th>
            <th>Deviation B</th>
            <th>Ratio C</th>
            <th>Excitation C</th>
            <th>Deviation C</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

***EDIT***

The error is coming from the `paging()` method in the `datatables.py`.

```
  File &#34;C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\datatables\datatables.py&#34;, line 102, in run
    self.paging()
  File &#34;C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\datatables\datatables.py&#34;, line 225, in paging
    if (self.request_values[&#39;iDisplayStart&#39;] != &#34;&#34; ) \
  File &#34;C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\webob-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\webob\multidict.py&#34;, line 99, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: &#39;iDisplayStart&#39;
```

***EDIT***
It seems to be failing this if statement in datatables.py:

```
def paging(self):
    """Construct the query, by slicing the results in order to limit rows showed on the page, and paginate the rest
    """
    pages = namedtuple('pages', ['start', 'length'])

if (self.request_values['iDisplayStart'] != "" ) \
    and (self.request_values['iDisplayLength'] != -1 ):
    pages.start = int(self.request_values['iDisplayStart'])
    pages.length = int(self.request_values['iDisplayLength'])

offset = pages.start + pages.length
self.query = self.query.slice(pages.start, offset)
```

which seems to me 'iDisplayStart' doesn't exist in the GET request dictionary

Comment: It suddenly gets `which` error?

Comment: the error in the title

Comment: Will u please provide full traceback?

Comment: I'll add it under "edit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling the wrong route......
I was accidentally calling the method directly instead of navigating to the page that contained the ajax call

these are my routes:

```
config.add_route('simple_example', '/simple_example')
config.add_route('test', '/test')

@view_config(route_name='test', renderer='templates/main.html')
def test(request):
    partial = ["Custom/test.html"]
    return dict(partial=partial)
```

test is the route to my view which returns the html containing the table and the datatable call.
Instead I kept calling 127.0.0.1:1234/simple_example which is the method returning data to the table